# HBase region servers going down when try to configure Apache Phoenix

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm using **CDH 5.3.1** and **HBase 0.98.6-cdh5.3.1** and trying to configure **Apache Phoenix 4.4.0**

As per the documentation provided in [Apache Phoenix Installation](http://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html)

- Copied phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-0.98-server.jar file in lib directory (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hbase/lib) of both master and region servers
- Restarted HBase service from Cloudera Manager.

When I check the HBase instances I see the region servers are down and I don't see any problem in log files.

[image]

I even tried to copy all the jars from the phoenix folder and still facing the same issue.

I have even tried to configure Phoenix 4.3.0 and 4.1.0 but still no luck.

Can someone point me what else I need to configure or anything else that I need to do to resolve this issue

Comment: did you installed by using parcels? or manual?

Comment: @AnilGupta I'm doing this manually. How can I use parcels to configure Phoenix??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to configure Apache Phoenix using Parcels. Following are the steps to install Phoenix using Cloudera Manager

1. In Cloudera Manager, go to Hosts, then Parcels.
2. Select Edit Settings.
3. Click the + sign next to an existing Remote Parcel Repository URL, and add the following URL: http://archive.cloudera.com/cloudera-labs/phoenix/parcels/1.0/. Click Save Changes.
4. Select Hosts, then Parcels.
5. In the list of Parcel Names, CLABS_PHOENIX is now available. Select it and choose Download.
6. The first cluster is selected by default. To choose a different cluster for distribution, select it. Find CLABS_PHOENIX in the list, and click Distribute.
7. If you plan to use secondary indexing, add the following to the hbase-site.xml advanced configuration snippet. Go to the HBase service, click Configuration, and choose HBase Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hbase-site.xml. Paste in the following XML, then save the changes.

   ```
   <property>
       <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
   </property>
   ```
8. Whether you edited the HBase configuration or not, restart the HBase service. Click Actions > Restart

For detailed installation steps and other details [refer this link](https://khodeprasad.wordpress.com/2015/10/14/configuring-apache-phoenix-in-cdh-5-4-3-using-cloudera-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, Phoenix4.4.0 is compatible with CDH version you are running. 
This discussion on mailing list will help you:http://search-hadoop.com/m/9UY0h2n4MOg1IX6OR1